Will the Nestjs develop "Spring-Cloud-Likely" framework "Nestjs-Cloud", which provide api gateway, service registry and discovery，load balance,
I find that the pattern of Nestjs microservices is quite different from Spring Cloud, in which there are some server components serving as api gateway, authentication, logger, rate-limit, service registry and discovery center. Therefore,I think that microservice solution Nestjs provides is not so complete, and I wonder if the more complete and powerful microservice solution will be developed.
I want to different opinions about the question i asked.Or, how can I build the architecture of project based on microservices  like Spring Cloud do。
